# How Jetpack Compose uses CursorLoader to get all-inclusive albums

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

My requirement is to obtain all the album and photo data, and customize the selection of photos.
Using `CursorLoader` before was very good and can meet my needs, but now that Jetpack Compose is fully used, so that `CursorLoader` can't get the context. At the same time, I understand that the `CursorLoader` is deprecated and [`ViewModel`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#loaders) should be used instead.

This is part of the code I used before

```kotlin
class AlbumLoaderManager(var activity: FragmentActivity, private var albumLoaderCallback: AlbumLoaderCallback) : LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    override fun onCreateLoader(id: Int, args: Bundle?): Loader<Cursor> {
        return CursorLoader(activity, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, null, null, PROJECTION[5] + " DESC")
    }

    override fun onLoadFinished(loader: Loader<Cursor>, cursor: Cursor) {

        val imageList = ArrayList<Image>()

        if (cursor.count > 0) {
            cursor.moveToFirst()

            do {
                val name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME))
                val path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA))
                val width = cursor.getFloat(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.WIDTH))
                val height = cursor.getFloat(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.HEIGHT))
                val time = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED))

                if (name != null && path != null) {
                    val image = Image(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), name,"file:///$path", width, height, time)
                    imageList.add(image)
                }

            } while (cursor.moveToNext())
        }

        albumLoaderCallback.albumLoaderFinish(splitFolder(imageList))
    }

    override fun onLoaderReset(loader: Loader<Cursor>) {

    }

    interface AlbumLoaderCallback {
        fun albumLoaderFinish(albumList: List<Album>?)
    }

    companion object {

        private val PROJECTION = arrayOf(
            MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.WIDTH,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.HEIGHT,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED
        )
    }

    init {
        LoaderManager.getInstance(activity).initLoader(0, null, this)
    }
}
```

How to use `ViewModel` to load all albums and photo data in Jetpack Compose?

Answer (score 0):

Can’t wait for the answer, I already have the result, the following code will get all the albums and photo contents, and the albums have been grouped

```
class AlbumViewModel : BaseViewModel() {

    val albumList = mutableStateListOf<Album>()

    fun getAllImages(context: Context) {

        val imageList = ArrayList<Image>()

        val uri  = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
        val resolver = context.contentResolver

        val  cursor = resolver.query(uri, PROJECTION, null, null, PROJECTION[5] + " DESC")

        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst()

            do {
                val name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME))
                val path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA))
                val width = cursor.getFloat(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.WIDTH))
                val height = cursor.getFloat(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.HEIGHT))
                val time = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED))

                if (name != null && path != null) {
                    val image = Image(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), name,"file:///$path", width, height, time)
                    imageList.add(image)
                }

            } while (cursor.moveToNext())

            cursor.close()
        }

        albumList.addAll(splitFolder(imageList))
    }

    companion object {

        private val PROJECTION = arrayOf(
            MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.WIDTH,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.HEIGHT,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED
        )
    }

    // 把图片按文件夹拆分，第一个文件夹保存所有的图片
    private fun splitFolder(imageList: MutableList<Image>?): List<Album> {

        val albums = ArrayList<Album>()
        albums.add(Album("All Image", imageList!!))

        if (imageList.isEmpty()) {
            return albums
        }

        for (i in imageList.indices) {

            val path = imageList[i].path
            val name = getFolderName(path)

            if (StringUtils.isNotEmptyString(name)) {
                val album = getFolder(name, albums)
                album.addImage(imageList[i])
            }
        }

        return albums
    }

    private fun getFolder(name: String, albums: MutableList<Album>): Album {
        if (!albums.isEmpty()) {
            val size = albums.size
            for (i in 0 until size) {
                val album = albums[i]
                if (name == album.name) {
                    return album
                }
            }
        }
        val newAlbum = Album(name)
        albums.add(newAlbum)
        return newAlbum
    }

    // Java文件操作 获取文件扩展名
    private fun getExtensionName(filename: String?): String {
        if (filename != null && filename.isNotEmpty()) {

            val dot = filename.lastIndexOf('.')
            if (dot > -1 && dot < filename.length - 1) {
                return filename.substring(dot + 1)
            }
        }
        return ""
    }

    // 根据图片路径，获取图片文件夹名称
    private fun getFolderName(path: String): String {
        if (StringUtils.isNotEmptyString(path)) {
            val strings = path.split(File.separator.toRegex()).dropLastWhile { it.isEmpty() }.toTypedArray()
            if (strings.size >= 2) {
                return strings[strings.size - 2]
            }
        }

        return ""
    }
}
```